# file is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL but already has one

Tags: javascript, firefox, meteor, source-maps

I just notice Firefox console outputs the following error for every single .js/.coffee file in my project (even the packages).

```
-file- is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
```

Chrome's console doesn't show anything. I tried deleting all the .map files and clearing Firefox's cache but I'm still getting the errors.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Did a search and found this SO question, asked only an hour prior :-)
BTW, this is on FF 27.

Comment: Seems to be a firefox bug: [925614](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925614). But it's a warning, not an error. Look for other error messages if your code isn't working.

Comment: @DS. - thanks for mentioning it was a warning. It's unhelpful that the message starts 'Error: ....' in addition to being a bug already

Comment: It appears even in latest Firefox 29 beta-5 and jQuery 1.10.2 .. switched to 1.11.0 it gone.

Comment: This still happens on Firefox 30 with angular

Comment: And still happens in Moz 31.0 and jQuery 1.10.2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a warning (not an error)
and it is a bug (<s>https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1020846</s> fixed in FF 33)

This warning/error also applies to other libs (angular, backbone, etc.)

Comment: According to the linked bug this is fixed in firefox 32, 33.

Answer (score 7):

I have been working on a project for over a year now, I have never seen this message until roughly the last Firefox update.

I received it using jQuery 1.9.x, so I just updated my jQuery to 1.11.x and the error went away.  I am now happy.

So, if you are using jQuery and see this Error/Warning, try updating your jQuery to the latest version.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For me this was `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 7):

In Firefox 27.0.1 I was getting this exact same error. I already have jQuery 1.11.0.

```
SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated.
Use //# instead kendo.dataviz.min.js:25
22:09:26.635 Error: http://localhost/project/Scripts/kendo.dataviz.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
```

I opened the `kendo.dataviz.min.js` and deleted the offending line:

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=kendo.dataviz.min.js.map
```

Comment: This is a different error, and you can fix it by just replacing "@" with "#"

Answer (score 5):

put your code inside

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
   //whatever
   });
```

then the message dissappears.

Comment: I think that is not always acceptable and since it is not webdev's code problem, it's not really them who should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

For the people using `Visual Studio 2013`, and have downloaded the `jQuery` libraries via `NuGet`, check your `jquery-x.x.x.min.js` and you'll find the text comment below that's popping this warning on `Firefox`.

```
// # sourceMappingURL=jquery-x.x.x.min.map
```

You can safely remove those lines.

Comment: This did it for me in jQuery and FullPageJS.

Answer (score 0):

Update jquery - from the jQuery website http://www.jquery.com/download

You can also download a sourcemap file for use when debugging with a compressed file. The map file is not required for users to run jQuery, it just improves the developer's debugger experience. As of jQuery 1.11.0/2.1.0 the //# sourceMappingURL comment is not included in the compressed file.