# Jquery v2.1.3 sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated

Tags: jquery

I read a lot of articles about this issue and even downloaded the jquery source map into the same directory as jquery after reading this

[sourceMappingURL from jquery generates 404 error in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157535/sourcemappingurl-from-jquery-generates-404-error-in-apache)

. But I still have the same error

```
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
```

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Does doing what the error told you to do not work?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to do what i am asked to do here. When i click on the link given by firebug it brings me inside  jquery at the first line where it is written
`/*! jQuery v2.1.3 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */`

Comment: Replace the `@` with `#` to suppress it, yes edit the jQuery file. This may be an issue with and older version of firefox [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759662/file-is-being-assigned-a-sourcemappingurl-but-already-has-one).

Comment: The problem is that i do not find any `@` aside of only one place in the script and that is deep inside the jquery 
`kc=/^([\w.+-]+:)(?:\/\/(?:[^\/?#]*@|)` and i am not sure that i have to replace that one . Do i ?

Comment: There should be a source mapping at the top of the page. But no not that one as it's part of a regular expression.

Comment: Yes normally but i am not finding one. Please check
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js 
Is there one there ?

Comment: Is that your only file, perhaps there is another js file causing this? I don't see anything in that code that could cause the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the [Jquery Map](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.map) for that version and placed it in the same directory. After restarting, that problem was no more